# Looking for significant variability of categorical data in columns of data frame

Tags: r, categorical-data, variability

I have a data frame with each column contains categorical data: 0,0.5,1,-1

```
           T116 T111 T11 T109 T108 T107 T105 T104 T55  T52 T58  T1
cg21277995  1.0  0.5 0.5  0.5    1  0.5  1.0  1.0 1.0  0.5 1.0 0.5
cg01324372  0.0  0.5 0.0  0.5    1  1.0  0.5  1.0 1.0  0.5 1.0 0.5
cg13836638  1.0  0.5 0.0  0.5    1  1.0  0.5  1.0 1.0  1.0 1.0 0.5
cg00002719  0.5  0.0 0.0  0.5    1  0.5  0.5  1.0 1.0  0.5 1.0 0.5
cg15804767  0.5  0.5 0.5  0.5    1  1.0  0.5  1.0 0.5  0.5 1.0 0.5
cg17228900 -1.0  0.5 0.5  0.5   -1  0.5  0.5  0.5 0.5 -1.0 0.5 0.0
```

I want to get only the columns that have a significant variability among the others. Is there any test to calculate the variability in each column compared with the others? Probably permutation tests? I want to obtain a p-value for each column and then select the best ones

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "significant variability among the others". I am also not sure exactly what you mean by "variability" since you say these data are categorical. I can think of various ways to think of this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**A permutation test works** provided you follow it up by a test for an unknown number of high outliers.

Here's an implementation, some illustrations, and a discussion.

---

#### Implementation

The test statistic itself consists of the column variances:

```
stats <- apply(data, 2, var)
```

Compute a permutation statistic by independently scrambling each row, obtaining the variances of all data columns, and sorting them:

```
var.prmttn <- function(x, center=FALSE) {
  if (center) x <- apply(x, 2, function(y) y - mean(y))
  sort(apply(apply(x, 1, sample), 1, var))
}
```

Repeat this a bunch of times to obtain the null distribution of the permutation statistic:

```
sim <- replicate(1000, var.prmttn(data))
```

This is our reference for assessing the actual statistic.  (For the use of the `center` parameter, see below.)

#### Illustrations

Let's synthesize some data in which all variables have randomly chosen values but have the same expected variance.  `prob` specifies the expected frequencies of the values in `values` and `n.obs` stipulates the number of rows:

```
set.seed(17)
names <- c(116, 111, 11, 109, 108, 107, 105, 104, 55, 52, 58, 1)
vars <- sapply(names, function(i) paste("T", i, sep=""))
values <- c(0, 1/2, 1, -1)
prob <- c(.1, .4, .3, .1)
n.obs <- 60
data <- data.frame(sapply(vars, 
        function(s) sample(values, n.obs, prob=prob, replace=TRUE)))
row.names(data) <- sapply(runif(n.obs), function(x) sprintf("cg%08d", floor(10^8*x)))
```

The null distribution in this case is the set of distributions of the sorted variances, which are effectively visualized with boxplots:

```
extent <- c(min(min(stats), min(sim)), max(max(stats), max(sim)))
extent <- 1.1 * (extent - mean(extent)) + mean(extent)
do.call(boxplot, list(lapply(1:dim(sim)[1], function(i) sim[i,]), 
                      ylim=extent, main="Permutation distribution",
                      ylab="Variance", xaxt="n"))
```

Over these we may superimpose the actual vector of test statistics, with appropriate labels to identify them:

```
points(sort(stats), pch=19, col="Red", cex=1.25)
text(rep(min(extent), length(stats)), labels=vars[order(stats)])
```

[image: Null boxplots]

Let's do this again but increase the expected variances of two of the columns (by giving them greater probabilities of exhibiting the extreme values $\pm 1$):

```
prob.alt <- c(.1, .1, .4, .4)
data$T55 <- sample(values, n.obs, prob=prob.alt, replace=TRUE)
data$T11 <- sample(values, n.obs, prob=prob.alt, replace=TRUE)
```

[image: Alternate boxplots]

We see *two* kinds of effects.  Sure enough, the two different variables are detected by having two large values.  At the same time, the values of all the rest of the variances are depressed compared to the null distribution.

#### Discussion

It may be difficult to obtain a useful p-value for such a result, given how changes in variance in one variable will affect both the null distribution and the apparent extremeness of variances in all the other variables.  This is especially the case when the number of high-variance variables is not known in advance.

This situation is ideal for applying a multiple outlier detection procedure to the variances of the variables.  One that searches for unusually large gaps among the largest values ought to perform well.  The [NIST handbook](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda35h.htm) provides some guidance and links to further reading.

Finally, if the means of the variables differ substantially, their variation can make the null distribution less useful as a reference. Instead, permute their *residuals* in the test rather than the values themselves by setting `center=TRUE` in `var.prmttn` (or, more efficiently, by centering the variables individually before running the test).